# How do I use a mouse listener to call another class?

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have bits and and pieces of the mouse listener, but I am not sure how to tie it all together. I am trying to have a tic tac toe game activate when the user clicks on the play games button. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.Color;

    public class Use_PF_Interface extends JFrame implements Pet_Fish_Interface, MouseListener
     {
        // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
        private JFrame window;
        private JPanel backgroundPanel;
        private JLabel lblBackgroundImage = new JLabel();
        private JButton feedButton = new JButton("Feed Fish");
        private JButton playGamesButton = new JButton("Play Game");
        volatile private boolean mouseDown = false;

        //creates frame window
        public Use_PF_Interface()
        {
           setTitle("Virtual Pet Fish");
           setSize(400, 400);

           //initializes panels and panel layout
           backgroundPanel = new JPanel(); 
           backgroundPanel.setOpaque(false); 
           backgroundPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

           lblBackgroundImage.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

           //sets background image of panel
           lblBackgroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("OCEAN2.jpg"));
           lblBackgroundImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
           lblBackgroundImage.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);


            //adds button to panels
            backgroundPanel.add(feedButton);
            backgroundPanel.add(playGamesButton);
            lblBackgroundImage.add(backgroundPanel);


            add(lblBackgroundImage);


            feedButton.addMouseListener(this);
            playGamesButton.addMouseListener(listener);

            addMouseListener(this);


            }//creates frame window

         /**
         * This method will create an action for the button.
         * @pre none
         * @return tic tac toe game
         * @param none
         * @post none
         */

         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
         {

             if (e.getButton() ==  MouseEvent.playGamesButton)
             {
               mouseDown = true;
               Tic_Tac_Toe();
              }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
             if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.feedButton)
             {
                mouseDown = false;

             }
         }

          public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
          {
          }
```

I am currently recieving this error: Use_PF_interface is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple. MouseListener is an Interface. An Interface is a class with methods, which the class that implements this interface, must contain. Even if these methods contain nothing, you have to include them in your code. So if you want to implement the MouseListener you have to override these 5 methods:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class Example implements MouseListener {

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

And by the way, can't you just use an ActionListener for that, what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is the issue, but should there be a mouseEntered method inside that class to override as mentioned?